# Angular Nativescript code sharing project wont read ttf, otf font or declaration

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-nativescript

I have a problem with font declaration and usage on native script angular project.

> The structure is as below:

[image: Structure]

The arbeit font is working fine, but the oc-format-sans is not getting recognized/loaded.

Declared like this for android only:

```
  font-family: "oc-format-sans-print-demi", "-OCFormatSans-PrintDm";
```

Comment: Did you try with non-code sharing projects, perhaps Playground already? Did the font work?

Comment: No i havent, but the ttf for arbeit font is working in the same project..

Comment: Just tried it in the playground and the font is working. Any insight @Manoj ?

Comment: As long the font file name and post script name are correct, it should work. Can you share the sample project to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the info @Manoj, The font declaration worked after rebuilding the build and removing platform as well as replacing the off with ttf fonts.